# How to extend .NET Core IFormFileCollection

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net5, c#-9.0, iformfile

I'm developing an ASP.NET Core 5 Web API project, I want to save a post which contains multiple files. Each file should includes name and title.

Here is my code:

```
public class PostDTO
{
    public Guid? CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Guid UserID { get; set; }
    public string PostTitle { get; set; }
    public string PostContent { get; set; }
    public string Tags { get; set; }

    public IFormFileCollection FileList { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromForm] PostDTO postDTO)
{
    if (postDTO == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(postDTO));

    List<PostAttachmentFileDataStructure> FileList = new();

    if (postDTO.FileList != null)
        foreach (var Attachment in postDTO.FileList)
            FileList.Add(PostAttachmentFileDataStructure.Create(Guid.NewGuid(), "FileTitle", Attachment));

        try
        {
            await commandBus.Send(PostCommand.Create(Guid.NewGuid(), postDTO.PostTitle, postDTO.PostContent, postDTO.CategoryId, postDTO.UserID, postDTO.Tags.NormalizedInput(), FileList));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return StatusCode(500);
        }

        return Ok();
}
```

As you know `IFormFile` and `IFormFileCollection` don't have any properties like `Title`. So I want to extend `IFormFileCollection` to add another property called `Title`.

Is there any way to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In backend:**

Instead of

```
public class PostDTO
{
    public Guid? CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Guid UserID { get; set; }
    public string PostTitle { get; set; }
    public string PostContent { get; set; }
    public string Tags { get; set; }

    public IFormFileCollection FileList { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromForm] PostDTO postDTO){...}
```

you should use:

```
public class PostDTO
{
    public Guid? CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Guid UserID { get; set; }
    public string PostTitle { get; set; }
    public string PostContent { get; set; }
    public string Tags { get; set; }
    public List<FileInfo> FileInfos { get; set; }
}

 public class FileInfo
    {
        public string title{ get; set; }
        public string filename { get; set; }
    }
```

and

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post( IFormCollection dto){...}
```

then in body you can convert data to your dto

```
PostDTO postDTO = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PostDTO>(dto["data"]);
```

for access to uploaded files you can use

```
dto.Files
```

**In frontend:**

```
    const data = {
            categoryId: "1",
            postTitle: "1",
            postContent: "1",
            userId: "1",
            tags: "1",
            fileInfos: [
              { title: "1", fileName: "1" },
              { title: "2", fileName: "2" },
            ],
          };
          const formData = new FormData();
          formData.append("data", JSON.stringify(data));
          formData.append("files", "file that has been uploaded");

      axios
        .post("your api URL", formData)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add a title to IFormFile,how do you pass title with file in your form?
Here is a demo to create a Model includes Title and IFormFile,and pass sample data with ajax:

Model:

```
public class FileModel
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public IFormFile File { get; set; }
    }
public class PostDTO
    {
        public Guid? CategoryId { get; set; }
        public Guid UserID { get; set; }
        public string PostTitle { get; set; }
        public string PostContent { get; set; }
        public string Tags { get; set; }

        public List<FileModel> FileList { get; set; }
    }
```

View:

```
<form>
    <input type="file" id="files" multiple/>
    <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="PostFiles()" />
</form>
<script>
function PostFiles() {
            var formData = new FormData();
            var files = $("#files").get(0).files;
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
            {
                formData.append("FileList[" + i + "].Title", "title"+i);
                formData.append("FileList[" + i + "].File", files[i]);

            }
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Post",
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (data) {
                }

            });
        }
</script>
```

result:
[image]